# Importing configuration values from json file to scss

Tags: json, vue.js, webpack, sass, bootstrap-4

I created a web application with Vuejs to which I added a json configuration file that allows me, for example, to enable or disable some sections. For the style of the application I added Bootstrap that I customized with a scss file.

Now in the scss file I have added some variables for colors that, however, I would like to move to the json file to have the configuration in one place. Unfortunately I'm not able to import the json file from the scss file and read its content.

Is there a method to read the json file from the scss file?

I tried to import with these routes:

- @import "./../json/config.json";
- @import "@assets/json/config.json";
- @import "Assets/json/config.json";

I installed [this npm package](https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer), and tried to add this `importer: jsonImporter()` css loader of 'vue.config.js', but still could not read the file.

*custom-bootstrap.scss*

```css
@import "./../json/config.json";
...
$blue: #3399ff;
$green: #33cc99;
$red: #cc3333;
$yellow: #ffcc00;

$danger: $red;
$info: $blue;
$success: $green;
$warning: $yellow;
...
```

*config.json*

```
...
"colors": {
  "danger": "#cc3333",
  "info": "#3399ff",
  "success": "#33cc99",
  "warning": "#ffcc00"
}
...
```

*vue.config.js*

```
const path = require("path");

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias
      .set("Assets", resolve("./src/assets/"))
      .set("Components", resolve("./src/components/"))
      .set("Constants", resolve("./src/constants/"))
      .set("Setup", resolve("./src/setup/"))
      .set("Store", resolve("./src/store/"))
      .set("Utils", resolve("./src/utils/"))
      .set("Views", resolve("./src/views/"));
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions.modules = [
          {
            preTransformNode(astEl) {
              if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
                const { attrsMap, attrsList } = astEl;
                if (attrsMap['data-test']) {
                  delete attrsMap['data-test'];
                  const index = attrsList.findIndex(x => x.name === 'data-test');
                  attrsList.splice(index, 1);
                }
              }
              return astEl;
            }
          }
        ];
        return options;
      });
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "@/assets/scss/_mixins.scss";
          @import "@/assets/scss/_z-index.scss";
          @import "@/assets/scss/custom-bootstrap.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I would like to set the colors of the scss file in this way:

```css
$danger: colors.danger;
$info: colors.info;
$success: colors.success;
$warning: colors.warning;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by editing the `vue.config.js` file as follows:

```
const path = require("path");
const jsonImporter = require('node-sass-json-importer');

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias
      .set("Assets", resolve("./src/assets/"))
      .set("Components", resolve("./src/components/"))
      .set("Constants", resolve("./src/constants/"))
      .set("Setup", resolve("./src/setup/"))
      .set("Store", resolve("./src/store/"))
      .set("Utils", resolve("./src/utils/"))
      .set("Views", resolve("./src/views/"));
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions.modules = [
          {
            preTransformNode(astEl) {
              if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
                const { attrsMap, attrsList } = astEl;
                if (attrsMap['data-test']) {
                  delete attrsMap['data-test'];
                  const index = attrsList.findIndex(x => x.name === 'data-test');
                  attrsList.splice(index, 1);
                }
              }
              return astEl;
            }
          }
        ];
        return options;
      });
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        importer: jsonImporter(),
        data: `
          @import "@/assets/scss/_mixins.scss";
          @import "@/assets/scss/_z-index.scss";
          @import "@/assets/scss/custom-bootstrap.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Then I created a `colors.json` file like this:

```css
{
  "danger": "#cc3333",
  "info": "#3399ff",
  "success": "#33cc99",
  "warning": "#ffcc00"
}
```

Finally I imported the json file with this path `@import "src/assets/json/colors.json";`

To use the properties from the json file I have to put `$` before the name of the key (e.g.: `$info`)